# Reactjs App.js is not supporting const assignment inside async function

Tags: reactjs

I have added cors module to my server.js - in my backend

Also, i have the below code in app.js in my front end. It shows some error. Please help to fix it.

[image]

Comment: syntax wrong -> `const get = async() =>` it should be and its `async` not `asynch` typo

Comment: The first line of your function should be `const get = async () => {`.

Comment: I have changed it. Now also i am getting error. Please suggest a solution

Comment: You didn't change `asynch` to `async`. And you should have a space between `async` and `()`.

Comment: [please do not post snippet of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 in your question is missing the error message and a mre to help others reproduce your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think it is a typo it is not `asynch()` it is like this `async ()`

Your function should be like this:

```
const get = async () => {
   const r = await fetch('http://localhost:3000)
   console.log(r)
}
```